# How to get row's every value individually and put them to array

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new in google scripts, please help me to understand.
my row is for example [11, 22, 33, 44]
i want get them individually
11
22
33
44
and maybe add to each of them +1 or +5 and put them in array like this
`

```
[[11], [22], [33], [44]]
```

or if +1

```
[[12], [23], [34], [45]]
```

`
How can i achieve this and what type of methods or functions i can use
Explain with examples please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Put all rows into columns

```
function putallrowsintocolums() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let nr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    sh.getRange(nr,i+1,r.length).setValues(r.map(e => [e]));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Descripton**

Here is a good reference to learning javascript [Javascript Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) Using [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) , perform a function for each element of the array.

**Script**

```
function unFlat() {
  try {
    let a = [11,22,33,44];
    let b = a.map( x => [x] );
    let c = 5;
    let d = a.map( x => [x+c])
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(d);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

6:10:04 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:10:04 AM  Info    [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ]
6:10:04 AM  Info    [ [ 11 ], [ 22 ], [ 33 ], [ 44 ] ]
6:10:04 AM  Info    [ [ 16 ], [ 27 ], [ 38 ], [ 49 ] ]
6:10:04 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Javascript Arrow function expresssion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)